# Генератор ссылок или что в этом роде

Tags: url, поиск, php

Решился написать поисковую систему, уже написал паука, который слушается `robots.txt`, но вот проблема: нужно сделать, чтобы робот сам находил сайты и индексировал. Как это реализовать?

Пробовал генерировать ссылки, но только было про индексировано только 4 из 79 сайтов, так как мало доменов вида `ght8.ru`

Может есть сайт, где есть список всех доменов?

Comment: врядли есть такой список...

Comment: Может как-то с whois сделать?

Comment: как? это сделать

Comment: Fast, не могли бы Вы порекомендовать источник, где Вы читали о создании поисковой системы?

Comment: нигде я не читал =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону Reverse IP Lookup, в сети много сайтов, которые предоставляют данную штуку. смысл в том, что можно узнать какие сайты/домены висят на определенном IP

вот пример: [reverse ip lookup](http://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=77.221.130.12)

Comment: О это идея генерировать IP и проверят сайты, спасибо

Comment: по этой ссылке выведутся все сайты/домены, которые висят на адресе 77.221.130.12

Comment: да пожалуйста)